# mongodb isValid function returns true for invalid ObjectIDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

so I have to check if a given input is a valid `ObjectID` and if that returns `true` I want to transform the value to a `ObjectID`. Unfortunately the validation returns true for "zzzzzzzzzzzz" and throws an exception while transforming the value.

I get the following error

> Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a
>   string of 24 hex characters

I tried to reproduce the problem:

```
const { ObjectID } = require("mongodb");

const value = "zzzzzzzzzzzz";
const isValid = ObjectID.isValid(value);

if (!isValid) { // this is true
  throw new Error("invalid ID");
}

ObjectID.createFromHexString(value); // throws exception
```

So why does the validation return `true` then? How can I fix that? My real project is a NestJs application so it would be nice to cast a value of type `any` to a typesafe `ObjectID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why does the validation return true then?

Because the [code](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/node_modules_bson_lib_bson_objectid.js.html). Line 338

Basically any valid input to the `ObjectID` constructor will return true with `ObjectID.isValid()`

Hence, for your case `ObjectID.isValid("zzzzzzzzzzzz")` is true because `new ObjectID("zzzzzzzzzzzz")` is a valid operation.

[More from an old documentation of node-mongodb-native driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/objectid/)

how about this:

```
const { ObjectID } = require("mongodb");
function isValidObjectID(id) {
  try{
    ObjectID.createFromHexString(id)
  }catch(e){
    return false
  }
  return true
}

console.log(`zzzzzzzzzzzz
isValid: ${isValidObjectID("zzzzzzzzzzzz")}`) // false

console.log(`5beec2f547643846af1d4dc3
isValid: ${isValidObjectID("5beec2f547643846af1d4dc3")}`) // true
```

Comment: hmm yeah, I could simply ignore the validation :)